# I want to insert members from php code into mysql database, it auto increment but no data is added

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I'm Trying to insert users into my database table users (membros) from my PHP page but for some reason it increments the values "membro_id) which is the primary key but no data is added to it. my pages have general header. The main one is:

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', 'chimasonline');
define('DB_PWD', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'chimasonline');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_DSN', 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME);
```

my Members file from model is Member.php (I put the INSERT INTO queries in comment mode to show what I already tried):

```
<?php
// PHP and MySQL Project
// members table data class

class Members
{
    public $debug = TRUE;
    protected $db_pdo;
    public $membersPerPage = 12;
    public $howManyMembers = 0;

    /*
     * Returns array of arrays where each sub-array = 1 database row of Members
     * @param int $offset [optional]
     * @return array $row[] = array('title' => title, 'description' => description, etc.)
     */
    public function getAllMembers($offset = 0)
    {
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `membros` ORDER BY `primeironome` LIMIT ' . $this->membersPerPage . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $content = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $content[] = $row;
        }
        return $content;
    }
    /*
     * Returns database row for 1 member
     * @param int $id = member ID
     * @return array $row[] = array('title' => title, 'description' => description, etc.)
     */
    public function getDetailsById($id)
    {
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `membros` WHERE `produto_id` = ?';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($id));
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
    /*
     * Returns database row for 1 member
     * @param string $email
     * @return array $row[] = array('title' => title, 'description' => description, etc.)
     */

      public function insertMember($data)
    {
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();


/*      $sql = 'INSERT * INTO `membros`(`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, 
       `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`)' . 'VALUES ([value-2],[value-3],
       [value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11])';

    /*            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros`( `nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, 
       `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`)' . 'VALUES ([value-2],[value-3],
       [value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11])';

  /*             $sql = 'INSERT INTO dbname . `membros`(`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, 
       `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`)' . 'VALUES ([value-2],[value-3],
       [value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11])';
 */ 
 /*
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros`(`primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, 
 `provincia`, `codigopostal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `email`)'
. 'VALUES (:primeironome,:ultimonome,:endereco,:cidade,:provincia,:codigopostal,
 :pais,:telefone,:email)';





    /*             $sql = 'INSERT INTO `chimasonline`.`membros` (`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`)'
       . 'VALUES (:pimeironome, :endereco, :cidade, :provincia, :codigopostal, :pais, :telefone, :balanco, :email, :password);';


                 $sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros` (`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`)'
       . 'VALUES (:nome, :endereco, :cidade, :estado_provincia, :codigo_postal, :pais, :telefone, :balanco, :email, :password);';


                 $sql = 'INSERT INTO `chimasonline`.`membros` (`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`) 
         ' . 'VALUES (primeironome ,endereco ,cidade ,provincia ,codigopostal ,pais , telefone,balanco ,email,password )';

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros`(`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, 
     `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`) VALUES = ?';   


  funcionou melhor esses dois tenho que explorar mais  lembrar q n tinha parametro    
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `chimasonline`.`membros` ( `primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, 
            `provincia`, `codigopostal`, `pais`, `email`, `telefone`, `password`) 
  . 'VALUES ( :primeironome ,:ultimonome, :endereco , :cidade , :provincia, :codigopostal , :pais , :email, :telefone, :password)';'  


   $sql = 'INSERT INTO `chimasonline`.`membros` ( `nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `password`) 
  VALUES ( hdd, f, bll, bgrio, 00000, qrf, password)'; 


       // $sql = 'INSERT INTO `chimasonline`.`membros` (`nome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `estado_provincia`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `balanco`, `email`, `password`) 
         ' . 'VALUES ( )';  

             $sql  = 'INSERT INTO `membros`(`primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `provincia`, 
             `codigopostal`, `pais`, `password`)' . 'VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';

           */     
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


               $stmt->execute(array($data));
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



                 return $result;

    } 
    /*
     * Returns database row for 1 member
     * @param string $email
     * @return array $row[] = array('title' => title, 'description' => description, etc.)
     */




    public function loginByName($email, $password)
    {
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `membros` WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($email, $password));
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
    public function getHowManyMembers()
    {
        if (!$this->howManyMembers) {
            $pdo = $this->getPdo();
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `membros`';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            // fetches as a numeric array
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            $this->howManyMembers = $result[0];
        }   
        return $this->howManyMembers;
    }
    /*
     * Returns array of arrays where each sub-array = 1 database row of Members
     * Searches name, address, city, state_province, country, email
     * @param string $search
     * @return array $row[] = array('title' => title, 'description' => description, etc.)
     */
    public function getMembersByKeyword($search)
    {
        $search = strip_tags($search);
        $search = str_ireplace(array("'",'-','"',';'), '', $search);
        $search = "'%" . $search . "%'";
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `membros` WHERE '
              . '`primeironome` LIKE ' . $search . ' OR '
              . '`cidade` LIKE ' . $search . ' OR '
              . '`email` LIKE ' . $search . ' ORDER BY `primeironome`';


        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $content = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $content[] = $row;
        }
        return $content;
    }
    /*
     * Returns a safely quoted value
     * @param string $value
     * @return string $quotedValue
     */
    public function pdoQuoteValue($value)
    {
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();
        return $pdo->quote($value);
    }
    /*
     * Returns a PDO connection
     * If connection already made, returns that instance
     * @return PDO $pdo
     */
    public function getPdo()
    {
        if (!$this->db_pdo) {
            if ($this->debug) {
                $this->db_pdo = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PWD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
            } else {
                $this->db_pdo = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PWD);
            }
        }
        return $this->db_pdo;
    }       

}
```

My addmember file (adicionarmembro.php) is:

```
?php
// assign defaults
//$result='';
$mailStatus = '';
$data = array('email'       => 'email', 
              'primeironome'    => 'primeironome', 
              'ultimonome'  => 'ultimonome', 
              'endereco'    => 'endereco', 
              'cidade'      => 'cidade', 
              'provincia'       => 'provincia', 
                          'codigopostal'    => 'codigopostal', 
                          'pais'        => 'pais',    
              'telefone'    => 'telefone',
                 // 'password'  => 'password',
                          //'password_confirmacao'  => 'password_confirmacao',
             // 'dnano'     => 0,
             // 'dnmes' => 0,
            //  'dndia'     => 0,
                 // 'dn'        => 0,
);
$error = array('email'    => '', 
              'primeironome' => '', 
              'ultimonome'  => '', 
              'endereco'      => '', 
              'cidade'    => '', 
                  'provincia'     => '',
              'codigopostal'  => '', 
                          'pais'      => '', 
              'telefone' => '', 
              'dn'        => '',
);
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = strip_tags($value);
    }
    if (isset($data['dnano']) && isset($data['dnmes']) && isset($data['dndia'])) {
        try {
            $bdateString = sprintf('%4d-%02d-%02d', $data['dnano'], $data['dnmes'], $data['dndia']);
            $bdate = new DateTime($bdateString);
            $today = new DateTime();
            $interval16 = new DateInterval('P16Y');
            $bdate16 = $today->sub($interval16);
            if ($bdate > $bdate16) $error['dn'] = '<b class="error">Tem que ter pelo menos 16 anos!</b>';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error['dn'] = '<b class="error">Data invalida</b>';
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

    } else {
        $error['dn'] = '<b class="error">Data invalida</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z0-9._-]+@(\w+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $data['email'])) {
        $error['email'] = '<b class="error">endereco de email Invalido</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9,. ]+$/i', $data['primeironome'])) {
        $error['primeironome'] = '<b class="error">O nome deve apenas conter letras, numeros, espacos "," ou "."</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9,. ]/i', $data['ultimonome'])) {
        $error['ultimonome'] = '<b class="error">O nome deve apenas conter letras, numeros, espacos "," or "."</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9,. ]/i', $data['endereco'])) {
        $error['endereco'] = '<b class="error">O endereco deve apenas conter letras, numeros, espacos "," ou "."</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9,. ]/i', $data['cidade'])) {
        $error['cidade'] = '<b class="error">A cidade deve apenas conter letras, numeros, espacos "," ou "."</b>';
    }
        if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9,. ]/i', $data['provincia'])) {
        $error['provincia'] = '<b class="error">A provincia deve apenas conter letras, numeros, espacos "," ou "."</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z][0-9][a-z] [0-9][a-z][0-9]$|^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/i', $data['codigopostal'])) {
        $error['codigopostal'] = '<b class="error"> codigo postal de Canada: A9A 9A9 <br />codigo postal de US: 99999 or 99999-9999<br />Se seu pais nao tem codigo postal digite 00000</b>';
        }
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9,. ]/i', $data['pais'])) {
        $error['pais'] = '<b class="error">O pais deve apenas conter letras, numeros, espacos "," ou "."</b>';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^\+[0-9]{1,3} \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/', $data['telefone'])) {
        $error['telefone'] = '<b class="error">O numero do telephone deve star no formato +CC AAA-CCC-DDDD</b>';
    }
    // Verifica se o formulario e valido
    $isValid = TRUE;
    foreach ($error as $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $isValid = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }

                  if ($isValid) {
        require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
                require './Model/Members.php';
                  $memberTable = new Members();
        $address = "****@****.com";
        $newName = $data['primeironome'] . ' ' . $data['ultimonome'];
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
        $body = 'Seja bemvindo a Chimas Online ' . $newName . '!'
              . '<br />Para confirmar o seu email, apenas responde a este email e nos faremos o resto...'
              . '<br />Desfrute!'
                          . '<br /> Clique em <a href = www.irenejovem.com> e continue a explorar os nossos produtos www.irenejovem.com';
        $mail->AddReplyTo($address,"ChimasOnline");
        $mail->SetFrom($address,"ChimasOnline");
        $mail->AddAddress($data['email'], $newName);
        $mail->Subject = 'Confirmacao de novo membro da ChimasOnline';
        $mail->AltBody = "Para ver a mensagem, use por favor um visualizador de email HTML compativel!"; // optional, comment out and test
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          $mailStatus = 'Erro ao enviar o email: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          $mailStatus = 'Email de confirmacao Enviado! Verifique o seu email e clique no link de confirmacao para efectivar o seu registro!';


                  $result = $memberTable->insertMember($data);


                }
    }
}
?>
    <div class="content">
    <br/>
    <div class="product-list">

        <h2>Cadastre-se na nossa pagina</h2>
        <br/>

        <b>Por favor, preencha a sua informacao.</b>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <?php if ($mailStatus) echo '<br /><b class="confirm">', $mailStatus, '</b><br />'; ?>
        <br />
        <form action="?page=adicionarmembro" method="POST">
            <p>
                <label>Data de Nascimento: </label>
                <select name="data[dnano]">
                    <?php if ($data['dnano']) { echo '<option>', $data['dnano'], '</option>'; } ?>
                    <?php $year = date('Y'); ?>
                    <?php for($x = $year; $x > ($year - 120); $x--) { ?>
                        <option><?php echo $x; ?></option>
                    <?php }     ?>
                </select>
                <select name="data[dnmes]">
                    <?php   
                    $month = array(1 => 'Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez');
                    if ($data['dnmes']) { 
                        printf('<option value="%02d">%s</option>', 
                               $data['dnmes'], $month[(int) $data['dnmes']]);
                    } 
                    for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
                        printf('<option value="%02d">%s</option>', $x, $month[$x]);
                        echo PHP_EOL;
                    }       
                    ?>
                </select>
                <select name="data[dndia]">
                    <?php if ($data['dndia']) { echo '<option>', $data['dndia'], '</option>'; } ?>
                    <?php for($x = 1; $x < 32; $x++) { ?>
                        <option><?php echo $x; ?></option>
                    <?php }     ?>
                </select> 

                <?php if ($error['dn']) echo '<p>', $error['dn']; ?>
            <p>
                <label>Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[email]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['email']); ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['email']) echo '<p>', $error['email']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>Primeiro Nome: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[primeironome]" value="<?php echo $data['primeironome']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['primeironome']) echo '<p>', $error['primeironome']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>Ultimo Nome: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[ultimonome]" value="<?php echo $data['ultimonome']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['ultimonome']) echo '<p>', $error['ultimonome']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>Endereco: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[endereco]" value="<?php echo $data['endereco']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['endereco']) echo '<p>', $error['endereco']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>Cidade: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[cidade]" value="<?php echo $data['cidade']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['cidade']) echo '<p>', $error['cidade']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                            <label>Provincia: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[provincia]" value="<?php echo $data['provincia']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['provincia']) echo '<p>', $error['provincia']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>Codigo Postal: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[codigopostal]" value="<?php echo $data['codigopostal']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['codigopostal']) echo '<p>', $error['codigopostal']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                            <label>Pais: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[pais]" value="<?php echo $data['pais']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['pais']) echo '<p>', $error['pais']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <label>Telefone: </label>
                <input type="text" name="data[telefone]" value="<?php echo $data['telefone']; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error['telefone']) echo '<p>', $error['telefone']; ?>
            <p>
            <p>
                <input type="reset" name="data[clear]" value="Clear" class="button"/>
                <input type="submit" name="data[submit]" value="Submit" class="button marL10"/>
            <p>
        </form>
    </div><!-- product-list -->
</div>
```

my users table is

[users table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p4hV.png)

but it shows like:
[users table after the INSERT command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vof0.png)

Please help, I'm desperated.

Comment: You're just assuming the queries will never fail. BAD idea. Change to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, or at least start checking return values from your DB calls. in "WARNING" mode, you'll get  warning (if display_errors/error_reporting allows them), but things will just return boolean false and continue onwards.

Comment: By the way, adding the `CREATE` code for your table makes it quicker for other people to re-create your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems most of the queries you made were pretty close. I would use this one:
`` INSERT INTO `membros` (`primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `provincia`, `codigopostal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `email`) VALUES (:primeironome, :ultimonome, :endereco, :cidade, :provincia, :codigopostal, :pais, :telefone, :email); ``
or this one:
`` INSERT INTO `membros` SET `primeironome` = :primeironome, `ultimonome` = :ultimonome, `endereco` = :endereco, `cidade` = :cidade, `provincia` = :provincia, `codigopostal` = :codigopostal, `pais` = :pais, `telefone` = :telefone, `email` = :email; ``

Call `prepare()` with that, and then make sure the array you pass to `execute()` looks like this (replace `[...]` with the actual value):
`["primeironome" => [...], "ultimonome" => [...], "endereco" => [...], "cidade" => [...], "provincia" => [...], "codigopostal" => [...], "pais" => [...], "telefone" => [...], "email" => [...] ]`

That should work just fine. If it doesn't, the problem is either in the column names (check the spelling) or in the actual values you're passing to the function (for example, passing an array would not go well).

### EDIT - doing this in the comments was awkward

Ok, so I'm trying to recreate your situation now. I created a table with the following CREATE code:

```
CREATE TABLE `membros` (
    `membro_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `primeironome` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `ultimonome` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `endereco` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    `cidade` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `provincia` CHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `codigopostal` CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `pais` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `datanascimento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `telefone` CHAR(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `balanco` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`membro_id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

First off some notes: the first and last name columns are too short I think (only 15 chars, I'd personally use 30 for first and 50 for last). Also, from your `password` column being only 16 characters I deduce 2 things: your max password length is too short (this makes brute-force attacks easier), and you store your passwords unhashed. **NEVER, NEVER store your passwords unhashed!**

Moving on to your actual problem: I literally executed the following code, and it works. All you have to do is make sure the `$data` array you ultimately pass to your query looks the same (with different values, *but with exactly the same keys*).

```
//I assume you have a working database connection, mine is the variable $connection
$data = ["primeironome" => "mi nome", "ultimonome" => "mi ultimo nome", "endereco" => "test 12345", "cidade" => "rio de janeiro", "provincia" => "no se", "codigopostal" => "12345 abc", "pais" => "BRA", "telefone" => "0123456789", "email" => "test@example.com"];
$prepStatement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `membros` (`primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, `provincia`, `codigopostal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `email`) VALUES (:primeironome, :ultimonome, :endereco, :cidade, :provincia, :codigopostal, :pais, :telefone, :email);");
$prepStatement->execute($data);
```

I also noted a bug in your original code while looking at this: your `$data` variable is already an array when you get it, but you pass it as `$stmt->execute(array($data));`. This should be `$stmt->execute($data);`.
You also try to `fetch()` results afterwards: an `INSERT` query does not return results, so there is nothing to fetch. If you want to know if it was successful, do this:

```
$status = $stmt->execute($data);
```

The `$status` variable will then contain `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`.

As a final point, this is what I recommended earlier for your `foreach` loop to parse the post data:

```
//make the default data array (with empty values, this is just to make sure the keys exist)
$data = ["primeironome" => "", "ultimonome" => "", "endereco" => "", "cidade" => "", "provincia" => "", "codigopostal" => "", "pais" => "", "telefone" => "", "email" => ""];

//REMOVE THIS LINE ->
//$data = $_POST['data'];

//now add your values from the $_POST array
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $data[$key] = strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

Now you **only** have the keys you defined in your $data array at the top of your file, and any which were not present in `$_POST` are still the default you set there.

Comment: I got the first two points but not the third (Sorry for being too dump :-) ) when you say to replace the actual values what do you mean? and in which file? I call this in my file adicionarmembro.php with the function: $result = $memberTable->insertMember($data); Should I add this code in file Membros after the execute or in my file adicionarmembro.php? - ["primeironome" => [...], "ultimonome" => [...], "endereco" => [...], "cidade" => [...], "provincia" => [...], "codigopostal" => [...], "pais" => [...], "telefone" => [...], "email" => [...] ]

Comment: The data comes from the array $data from the user in the webpage

Comment: @IreneJovem `$memberTable->insertMember($data)` should be fine, as long as $data contains **all** the keys you define with `:` in your query (so `$data = ["primeironome" => "mi nome", "ultimonome" => "mi ultimo nome", etc.]`

Comment: Getting the following error:Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 149
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 149
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 149. Looks like the array data and my database are not matching is it?

Comment: It does appear that you have more/less of the `:` variables in your query than you have in your $data array. Could you call a `print_r()` on your $data variable and give me the results? Also print the exact query you're preparing please. P.S. I will not be able to answer again until tomorrow.

Comment: Tried now the second set and getting the error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 112

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do my homework and will post it for yu to see tomorrow.

Comment: Used the print_r as guided and the results were: Array
(
    [0] => dnano
    [1] => dnmes
    [2] => dndia
    [3] => email
    [4] => primeironome
    [5] => ultimonome
    [6] => endereco
    [7] => cidade
    [8] => provincia
    [9] => codigopostal
    [10] => pais
    [11] => telefone
    [12] => submit
) It's amazing. it has offcourse more items and I do not know how the submit is there as well.

Comment: The query used is: $sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros`(`primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, 
 `provincia`, `codigopostal`, `pais`, `telefone`, `email`)'
. 'VALUES (:primeironome,:ultimonome,:endereco,:cidade,:provincia,:codigopostal,
 :pais,:telefone,:email)';

Comment: how will I take the date out? it gives me the day, month and year of birth. I need the user to place this data separeterly but in my database I have it as one like 0000-00-00.

Comment: tried to create more columns in database with dnano, dnmes and dndia (althought it's not what I wanted) just to see if this time it would include but did not. used: $sql = 'INSERT INTO `membros`(`primeironome`, `ultimonome`, `endereco`, `cidade`, 
 `provincia`, `codigopostal`, `pais`, `dnano`, `dnmes`, `dndia`, `telefone`, `email`)'
. 'VALUES (:primeironome,:ultimonome,:endereco,:cidade,:provincia,:codigopostal,
 :pais,:dnano,:dnmes,:dndia,:telefone,:email)'; and the erros are:

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 155

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 155

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 155

Comment: OK, first things first: the array you printed **does not use named keys**. You probably defined it like `$data = array($value1, $value2, etc.)`. It should be `$data = array("primeironome" => $value1, "ultimonome" => $value2, etc.)`. The query itself looks alright, except that you might need a space before the word `VALUES`.

Comment: Can you please have alook on the last code from my post? it's the file adicionarmembro.php (addmember) and I think the array is the way you sugested for array $data. I may be making some confusion please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The way you define `$data` at the top of "adicionarmembro.php" is correct. However, if you use `print_r()` and it shows you `[0] => $value, [1] => $value, ...` it means that the final array you passed **does not** have the same structure you define in adicionarmembro.php. If it did you would see `[primeironome] => $value, [ultimonome] => $value, ...`. I can see you overwrite the $data array just after you define it with `if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];`. To see what is happening to your array I recommend adding a `print_r()` before and after each place you edit it.

Comment: You are completly rigth. I've put print_r before the $_POST and it showed me less parameters than the output:Array
(
    [0] => email
    [1] => primeironome
    [2] => ultimonome
    [3] => endereco
    [4] => cidade
    [5] => provincia
    [6] => codigopostal
    [7] => pais
    [8] => telefone
)

Comment: I'm wondering how can I solve this as I need to get the data from the form in order to the user put his data and I need to check the data before I consider the form valid. that's why I have this point in there. Any idea?

Comment: Well, there are multiple things you need to consider. 1. Do you want to validate your form client side or server side? Client side (in javascript) has the advantage that if your form is invalid, you can choose not to POST it (until the user fixes it). 2. It's good you loop through your `$data` array after the POST, but I would slightly change it. Make sure all the values you need in your query are added to $data with good default(empty) values (like `NULL` or `''`). Then change your foreach loop to:

Comment: `foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
{
    if (isset($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $data[$key] = strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
    }
}`. This only overwrite the keys you actually received in your POST (sorry for the delay, something came up)

Comment: I understand. I'm the one that should saysorry for taking a lot of your time. I did it and removed:$data[$key] = strip_tags($value); is it rigth? but the results are the same :-(

Comment: Ok, I have now edited my answer above with a *lot* of extra information. I have written out all the actual parts which have anything to do with the database and your array. It is now up to you to make sure the `$data` array you use is correct. I hope this solves the issue for you. :)

Comment: It's really nice of you to recreate my situation and the info on the db, code and fetch were good that's why I was getting thar array to string error. I'm doing the changes now. based on your sugestion I should insert $data=["primeironome"=>" .... in the Members.php and the second code in addicionarmembro.php? I've figting with that for so long that I just want to make sure I do it rigth :-)

Comment: `$data` can come from anywhere you want it to, just make sure the keys are correct. The code preparing/executing the query goes into your Member.php `insertMember()` function. The foreach code and the "default" `$data` variable replace the ones you already have in adicionarmembro.php. I have ignored all your other code: if you have problems with validating the input or other things you should put that in a new question: here I just answered the database questions.

Comment: wawwww at least something is happening. I got in my database the data input in the first code mi nome etc... uf. and now how can I input the data posted inthe web by the user? I'm happy already

Comment: The array before the $_POST is empty Array() and the one after the post is the same as before but no errors:Array
(
    [0] => email
    [1] => primeironome
    [2] => ultimonome
    [3] => endereco
    [4] => cidade
    [5] => provincia
    [6] => codigopostal
    [7] => pais
    [8] => telefone
    [9] => submit
)

Comment: Just do not know what to try anymore:-)

Comment: You're still getting numeric keys. I don't know how you are filling that array, but **don't** do `$data[] = $value` <- that will give you numbered keys. Also, if you do `$data[$key] = $value` make sure that `$key` is the **string name** you want (like "primeironome" or "email").

Comment: Chaged the errormode to exception and got the following error message:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php:193 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php(193): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/View/adicionarmembro.php(16

Comment: 4): Members->insertMember(Array) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/index.php(89): include('/Applications/M...') #3 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/chimasonline/Model/Members.php on line 193

Comment: As per advise used: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES); in the begining of adicionarmembro.php and could see that the post works but at the end the array becames 0: _SERVER["argv"] -  
Array
(
    [0] => page=adicionarmembro
) I wish I could put a picture of the screen for you to see. Is there any way I can do it in here?

Comment: but the _POST["data"] - Array
(
    [dnano] => 1980
    [dnmes] => 01
    [dndia] => 1
    [email] => test@gmail.com
    [primeironome] => TesteNome
    [ultimonome] => TesteUltimoNome
    [endereco] => TestEndereco
    [cidade] => TesteCidade
    [provincia] => TesteProvincia
    [codigopostal] => 00000
    [pais] => TestePais
    [telefone] => +24 492-378-7896
    [submit] => Submit
)

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can do to help you. Your error is very clear: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`, so you have fewer/more parameters in your `$data` array than you prepared in your query using the `:` names. As I said before you should `print_r()` your array every time after you edit it to find where it goes wrong. When you call `print_r()` on your `$data` at the top of the `insertMember()` function the keys should look exactly like my examples (so no missing or extra keys).

Comment: So the final `$data` array **should not** contain the `submit`, `dnano`, etc. keys which you have above, because **you did not put those keys in your query**.